# Solr: Searching fields those do not match fully

Tags: full-text-search, solr

I have a Index with field productname.

I have following in the index.

1. ".net framework"
2. "**microsoft** .net framework **programming**"
3. ".net framework 4.0 **programming**"
4. "**Microsoft programming**"

If I put the query **".net framework"** it should search 1st 3 items.
If I put **"Microsoft Programming"** it should search 2 and 4.
If only **programming** then last 3.

I have read dictionary,stemming, text analysis. but unable to do above.

What changes should I make in the schema and query to full-fill above.

Thanks a ton,
Shrika

Comment: post the fieldType you're using and the exact query you're running.

Comment: yes a post of your schema for that field would help...

Comment: Have you definitely set indexed=true on the field? If not, solr would look for exact matches

Answer (score 0):

A sample schema will certainly be helpful for people to diagnose your problem. When I have similar issues, one thing I tried is to use "Field Analysis" tool comes with Solr Admin tool. It'll show you how the query and value are transformed and if they match or not.